# How to make PHP for loop to count down instead of up?

Tags: php, for-loop

I am using PHP to create a dropdown box with years from 1900 to 2012.  However, I'd like to have 2012 at the top of the list (i.e. count down from 2012 to 1900 instead of up from 1900 to 2012).

Any help you can provide would be great! :)

```
<select id="year">                  
<option value="">----</option>
    <?
    for ($i = 1900; $i <= 2012; $i++){
        echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
    }   
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: you should look at php doc: [http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php). You can do any increment or decrement in 3rd argument.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for($i = 2012; $i >= 1900; $i--)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of increment, decrement the initialized value and echo the value.

```
for ($i = 2012; $i >=1900 ; $i--)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
}
```